# Validaciones en Class Based View... form_valid o form_invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hay algo que no entiendo a la hora de realizar validaciones en vistas basadas en clases(`CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc), tengo entendido que se pueden hacer con el metodo `form_valid` y después guardarlo con un simple `form.save()`

Pero que tal si yo quiero entrar a un elemento dentro de ese formulario, como por ejemplo el `username` de un usuario o el `email`, también cosas como verificar si un titulo ya existe o una url fue agregada antes de que se envie el formulario.

¿Cómo podría realizar eso?

¿Esas variables se almacenan en `form.cleaned_data[variable]`?

Si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, lo agradeceré.

Comment: Si, se supone que ese método recibe como argumentos un `form` el cual es la instancia de tu formulario, con el puedes hacer lo mismo que harías en una vista basada en función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Como ves en este ejemplo la mejor forma es pasar el formulario a través de la función y con el parámetro instance agregamos el campo que deseemos modificar. En tu caso sería igual, solo que en ves de created_by reemplaza por username o por el field de tu caso.

Si tu class no definiste form, igualmente lo pones, django ya sabe cuál form se está manipulando. Recuerda manipular el súper con el nombre de tu clase

Comment: Gracias!, creo que ahora estoy en entiendo un poco mas el tema de las validaciones en Django

Answer (score 1):

Las vistas CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, tienen una variable en común:

```
self.object
```

En está variable se almacena "instancia/objecto" que usted está manipulando en el formulario. Note que cada ves que usted guarde el formulario en estás vistas a exception de DeleteView, form_valid guarda los cambios y esa nueva instancia la almacena en self.object.

```
self.object = form.save()
```